# Flask app doesn't reroute even when the terminal shows code 200

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am working on a project wherein based on availability of a time slot, a person can book an appointment.

Once, you click on the available time slot, it should redirect you to a page called Success (for now). However, this doesn't seem to be working. I replaced it with redirection to login (which works when I have to redirect from signup to login) and I am still getting the same error.

```
@app.route('/dashboard/<int:id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def dashboard(id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        json_dict = request.get_json()
        day = json_dict['day']
        time = json_dict['time']

        booking = Schedule(day=day, time=time, bookingId=id)
        db.session.add(booking)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for("success"))

    bookings_closed = list(Schedule.query.all())
    temp_dict = {}
    for i in bookings_closed:
        if i.day in temp_dict:
            temp_lst = temp_dict[i.day]
            if len(temp_lst) == 4:
                print("No available slot for this day")
            else:
                temp_lst.append(i.time)
        else:
            temp_dict[i.day] = [i.time]

    user = User.query.get_or_404(id)
    return render_template('dashboard.html',
                           booked=temp_dict,
                           name=user.username)
```

^ The above is the python code for where it is not working

```
@app.route('/success', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def success():
    return render_template("sucess.html")
```

^ The above is the success method 
Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Can you also add the "success" method here?

Comment: I have added the success method above.